# How to interpret the dendrogram graph axis (hierachical clustering )?

Tags: clustering, python, hierarchical-clustering, matplotlib

Here is the reproducable code with dataset used

`from scipy.cluster import hierarchy

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ytdist = np.array([662., 877., 255., 412., 996., 295., 468., 268.,400., 754., 564., 138., 219., 869., 669.])

Z = hierarchy.linkage(ytdist, 'single')

plt.figure()

dn = hierarchy.dendrogram(Z)

## Now plot in given axes, improve the color scheme and use both vertical and horizontal orientations:

hierarchy.set_link_color_palette(['m', 'c', 'y', 'k'])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 3))

dn1 = hierarchy.dendrogram(Z, ax=axes[0],

above_threshold_color='y',orientation='top')

dn2 = hierarchy.dendrogram(Z, ax=axes[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VweuS.png), above_threshold_color='#bcbddc',orientation='right')

hierarchy.set_link_color_palette(None)  # reset to default after use

plt.show()`

**Once I execute the above plot I got a plot below, I request you to assist me with interpretation of the axis !!!** [image: hierachical clustering plot]

My doubts are:
 1. When the dataset are in the range of 138 to 996, Why the plot axis varies from 0 to 300 ?
 2. What does 0,1,2,3,4,5 on the plot represent ?

Answer (score 0):

1. The height is a distance, not absolute coordinates.
2. The labels 0,1,2... are row numbers.

Comment: Thank you. 
1. Height is the distance of what meaning which distance it refers to? What can this be compared with for this dataset ?


2. Also there is only 1 row
How does the

`ytdist = np.array([662., 877., 255., 412., 996., 295., 468., 268.,400., 754., 564., 138., 219., 869., 669.])`
has row number from 0 to 5

Comment: See the documentation of [hierarchy.linkage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html). This array represents a **1d compressed distance matrix**. 6 choose 2 = 15.

Comment: I tried to understand from the documentation. This statement is unclear to me since ages **If y is a 1d compressed distance matrix, then y must be a (n 2) sized vector where n is the number of original observations paired in the distance matrix.**